# Custom uiview - Draw several objects (multiple rectangular with different attributes)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview

Usually I find here the solution for all my questions but this time I had to create a question. I am fairly new to custom objects and I am trying to create a Custom View that has several different elements layered over each other.

I managed to draw the background with
**-(void)drawRect:rect** 
and added a text label in **initWithCoder**.
But now I want to add multiple rectangular elements.

EDIT: With yurishs comment about UIBezierPath class I managed to draw rectangulars in the **(void)drawRect:rect** function. I also wanted to create an image in it but i read that to use images in **(void)drawRect:rect** is a bad idea. So I tried to create the UIBezierPath in initWithCoder:

```
[[UIColor blueColor] setFill];
UIBezierPath *rect = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRect:CGRectMake(0,0,200,200);
[rect fill]
```

but nothing is displayed.

Has someone an idea or example how something like this can be achieved?

Comment: If you want just draw rectangles in `drawRect` use `UIRectFrame`, `UIRectFill` functions and `UIBezierPath` class.

Comment: Make sure you read ["Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/introduction/introduction.html).  `UIBezierPath` and other drawing methods can be used only when there is a current graphic context, most often inside `drawRect:` method. When `initWithCoder` is called there is no graphic context.